# Decompress a gzip-compressed HTTP-Response (chunked encoding)

Tags: http, gzip, compression, chunked-encoding

like descriped in the title, I want to decompress a HTTP-Resonse.
Here is what I do:

1. receive the http-response
2. check the content-encoding (lets assume its gzip)
3. exctract the content from the http-response ( the result of this point is a byte array that contains the content of the HTTP-Message )
4. Try to decompress the content-byte-array

Last Point is not working. I get this error: "The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream."

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Edit: Since there is no answer yet, I post my decompress-code here:

```
    public static byte[] Decompress_GZip(byte[] gzip)
    {
        using (GZipStream stream = new GZipStream(new MemoryStream(gzip),
                                   CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
            {
                int count = 0;
                do
                {
                    count = stream.Read(buffer, 0, size);
                    if(count>0)
                    {
                        memory.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                    }
                }
                while (count > 0);
                return memory.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
```

What I have thought of yet: Might there be any problem with the endianess? Maybe the GZip stream cannot deal with the network byte-order.

Edit:
At least I noticed, this error just occurs when receiving chunked-messages. Lets assume a chunked message looks like that:

```
STATUS-LINE
HEADER_1 /cr/n
...
HEADER_n /cr/n
/cr/n
CHUNK1_SIZE /cr/n
CHUNK1_DATA /cr/n
...
CHUNKn_SIZE /cr/n
CHUNKn_DATA /cr/n
0 /cr/n
```

Thats what I guess, what I have to do to decompress the message:

1. Extract `CHUNK1_DATA` to `CHUNKn_DATA` (without the `/cr/n` and without `0`, the last chunk)
2. Concat `CHUNK1_DATA` ... `CHUNKn_DATA` to one `byte-array`
3. Decompress `byte-array` with the code above

I'd really appreciate an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I just tried myself and it worked as I described it in my Question. If your interested into my code, just commend or write me a message.

Comment: I am not able to send data in chunks properly from server side. Is there any constraints on the size of chunk that has to be transmitted, i.e. some minimum size of every packet

Comment: with "minimum size of every packet" ur talking about a minimum chunk-size? I've never read anything about a minimum chunksize. Since the last chunk has the size 0, I guess theres no minimum chunksize. Do you use any chunk-headers? Do you state the right length at chunksize? Do you use the right header-field? (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.11)

Comment: Thats how a chunked message has to look like: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.6.1